# Retrieve data from SP inside of From

Tags: sql-server-2012, stored-procedures

Goal:
Retreive a list of data from a stored procedure that is acting as a database name. When you have retrieved the list from stored procedure, I want to make another new data manipulation.

Problem:
I would like to use [sp_Test] to retrieve the data from the syntax code "FROM" but it does not work. Do you know how to solve it?

[image]

```
create table datatable (id int,
                        name varchar(100),
                        email varchar(10),
                        phone varchar(10),
                        cellphone varchar(10),
                        none varchar(10)                        
                       );

insert into datatable values
  (1, 'productname', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'), 
  (2, 'cost', '20', 'A', 'A', 'A'),
  (3, 'active', 'Y', 'A', 'A', 'A');

insert into datatable values
  (4, 'productname', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'), 
  (5, 'cost', '20', 'A', 'A', 'A'),
  (6, 'active', 'Y', 'A', 'A', 'A');


insert into datatable values
  (7, 'productname', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'), 
  (8, 'cost', '20', 'A', 'A', 'A'),
  (9, 'active', 'Y', 'A', 'A', 'A');


CREATE PROCEDURE [sp_Test]
as
begin
    set nocount on

    SELECT a.name, a.email, a.phone
    FROM datatable a 

end
```

Comment: ,Have you tried this way like . Select * from DatabaseName.SchemaName.TableName;

Comment: This context in my case it doesn't fit to fulfill the purpose. Sorry..

Comment: what exactly you want . can you clarify again for better understanding.

Comment: Please read the updated message above.

Answer (score 2):

That is not a supported syntax as a stored procedure can return multiple result sets or do other data manipulations and return nothing.

You would need to convert your stored procedure to a [table valued function](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) or insert the results into a temp table.

Answer (score 1):

```
create table #tmp1
(   name varchar(100), email varchar(10),phone varchar(10))


insert INTO #tmp1
EXEC [sp_Test]

select * from #tmp1
```

Comment: Why not just Exec [sp_Test] ? What do you want with it ?

Comment: I want to retrieve the data from SP_Test and make a new data manipulation.

Comment: you cannot do it directly.You have to save into a stage table/temp/var table and then use this new object